# Unable to update my database

Tags: php

So I was doing my edit page for my html form, however it is not updating the database and it always show me error message update fail. I was wondering if there is any error in my codes or query.

This is my query

```
$queryupdate = "Update anno 
                SET where id = '$no' 
                and title = '$row' and serial_no = '$no' 
                and type = '$type' and anno = '$row1' ";
```

Comment: your query is wrong which field you wants to update

Comment: $queryupdate = "Update anno SET title = '$row',serial_no = '$no',type = '$type',anno = '$row1'  where id = '$no' "; try something like this

Comment: You're using `WHERE` on all fields, instead of stating which fields to update. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: By the way you tagged PHP for your question, even though it does not have anything to do with PHP, you should have used SQL tag instead.

Comment: Your query is wrong and missing the column name which you want to update.

Comment: Tried user336779 method but still doesnt work. Hmm do you guys need to have a look at the whole page of codes?

Comment: you better post your full code as to where those variables are set, including which MySQL API you're using to connect with. Your question is unanswerable in its present state.

Comment: Start reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/ and Google "mysql tutorial". I for one won't be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: hi these are my full page of codes.

<?php
include "dbFunctions.php";
session_start();
$msg = "";
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo "You are not logged in.<br/>";
    echo "please login <a href ='login.php'>login</a>";
}
$no = $_POST['id'];
$type = $_POST ['type'];
$row = $_POST['title'];
$row1 = $_POST['anno'];


$query = "Select * from anno where serial_no = '$no'and type = '$type'and title = '$row' and anno = '$row1'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_fetch_row($result) == 1) {
    $msg = "no change has been made";
} else {

Comment: $queryupdate = "Update anno SET title = '$row', serial_no = '$no', type = '$type', anno = '$row1' where id = '$no'";
    $resultupdate = mysqli_query($link, $queryupdate);
    if ($resultupdate) {
        $msg = "changes has been made";
    } else {
        $msg = "update failed";
    }
}
?>


is there a way i could organsize my codes as its super messy here

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong:

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnToModify = newValue WHERE coniditons;
```

in your case you did not specify the column to be modified and jumped ahead to the condition.

Comment: changed it to  
$queryupdate = "Update anno SET title = '$row',serial_no = '$no',type = '$type',anno = '$row1' where id = '$no'
Still having an error though

Comment: how come your table name is anno and you are trying to modify its value (anno='$row1')? you can only modify columns' values!

Comment: oh sorry in my database i have a column called anno too, its 2 different things

Comment: that is not a good practice, anyway try using the following syntax: tableName.ColumnName (anno.anno='$row1') in your case, see if that solves your problem. if not please post the error code and more details about your code

Comment: hi i tried anno.anno but doesnt work, i posted my codes on top but its a little messy as i dont know how to organsize it.
the error message is actually from my if, else which is (Update failed)

Comment: remove the 'else { $msg = "update failed"; }' temporarily and try, then you can read the actual error.

Comment: okay so i removed it and my page went blank, no message appeared but its not saving into database too

Comment: make sure that your error displaying is enabled in your php.ini file, located the 'display_errors' in it and set it to on 'display_errors = on'

Comment: normally when therre is an error they will display is but for now is totally empty

Comment: remove the last PHP closing tag  '?>' in your pages (to avoid header's issues), and try again.

Comment: theres an syntax error if i didnt close it. Was wondering if you have skype so i could actually share screen to you and hopefully able to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Skype, please try to breakdown your code and troubleshoot it piece by piece, at least find the error which is causing the functions and posted it in a proper way.

Comment: i was thinking if its the query but i just cant seems to find the error

Comment: Ok, if you suspect that it is the query, go to your database system (MySQL or whatever) and test the query directly with dummy values, there you can know if it is your query causing the problem or not. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing like that ?

```
$queryupdate = "Update anno 
                SET title = '$row' and serial_no = '$no' 
                and type = '$type' and anno = '$row1' where id = '$no' 
                ";
```